# Error: No provider for t ONLY in --prod mode

Tags: angular, npm

I've read that certain modules or services which are not provided etc can cause this issue, but everything seems to be in place.

The full error is:

```
vendor.96643eaf6ee79e7b894d.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: No provider for t!
at x (vendor.96643eaf6ee79e7b894d.bundle.js:1)
at S (vendor.96643eaf6ee79e7b894d.bundle.js:1)
at t._throwOrNull (vendor.96643eaf6ee79e7b894d.bundle.js:1)
at t._getByKeyDefault (vendor.96643eaf6ee79e7b894d.bundle.js:1)
at t._getByKey (vendor.96643eaf6ee79e7b894d.bundle.js:1)
at t.get (vendor.96643eaf6ee79e7b894d.bundle.js:1)
at ze (vendor.96643eaf6ee79e7b894d.bundle.js:1)
at qe (vendor.96643eaf6ee79e7b894d.bundle.js:1)
at Be (vendor.96643eaf6ee79e7b894d.bundle.js:1)
at ze (vendor.96643eaf6ee79e7b894d.bundle.js:1)
b @ vendor.96643eaf6ee79e7b894d.bundle.js:1
```

Any help to be able to deploy successfully in production mode would be amazing. I cannot find an error with such little information. Does anyone know a way to expand the error to get something which is useful for debugging?

**SOLUTION from comments**
If adding the "--aot false" flag to the ng serve stops the error from being displayed, --aot added alone will display the relevant aot error to enable debugging.

Comment: what are the versions of ur angular cli and angular ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to capitalize on what @LucaTaccagni said : putting your application in production mode this way is *next to useless*.

This variable is used by Angular to detect the production mode in your code, but it's not used by the CLI.

If you want to simulate a real build on your local device, run this

```
ng serve --prod --env dev
```

**EDIT** If the AOT mode is the issue, you can do just that

```
ng serve --aot
```

This will set a lot of flags to true (such as, for instance, AOT compilation), while changing only the variable won't affect your build.

But as he said, once you've done that, you can debug.

Comment: This presents no change. I can deploy in --prod mode but only if I set  --aot to false.

Comment: Yeah well if you can deploy in prod mode with the AOT flag to false, then you can't deploy in prod mode. And if you can't deploy with the AOT flag, then you should definitely use my command, it will show you your mistake, but without your code being minified.

Comment: Npm isn't related to the CLI, even less to post-build errors ... But sure, if you have some time to lose, go ahead !

Comment: Well, i did what you suggested, the console message stayed the same, i assumed i wasn't on the same page as you. Where's the information i can use to debug specifically?

Comment: Oh I'm glad you kept us posted ! Did you try the other command I gave in the edit ? This should prevent the minification, since you know where to look (aot)

Answer (score 1):

in your environment.ts file try changing this flag:

```js
 export const environment = {
          production: true, // should be false by default
```

and then try building again in develop mode (ng serve should works). Now you should be able to debug.

The error you see: `t` is a variable minimized from the minification that the compiler do when you build your project, necessary to shadow your code to client.

Comment: You're right. I faced that issue long time ago so i forgot the `ng serve --prod`. Up vote of course =)

Comment: When --prod is applied, does the environment.prod.ts version not get ran? This is already set to true.

I've just re-built the application the error changed to ERROR Error: No provider for t!
    at x (core.es5.js:1169)
    at S (core.es5.js:1207)
    at t._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
    at t._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
    at t._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
    at t.get (core.es5.js:2489)
    at ze (core.es5.js:9492)
    at qe (core.es5.js:9533)
    at Be (core.es5.js:9503)
    at ze (core.es5.js:9488)

Comment: who handles which environment is chosen is `--env` flag